# When calculating the statistical power of a t-test, do I need to consider the uncertainty of the single values?

Tags: statistical-power, uncertainty, errors-in-variables

I have a question regarding calculating the power for a statistical test that includes data which are estimated by a model (means they have an uncertainty):

I want to find out if two piles of stones differ significantly in weight (let's say only around 5%).
To find an answer, I would measure the weight of each stone in the two piles. If they are normally distributed, I could do a two-sided t-test with the hypothesis that both piles are equally heavy.

Since I know the sample size (number of stones in each pile), the expected effect size (5%/std(weights)) and define an acceptable rejection limit (alpha = 0.05), I should be able to calculate the power (1 - beta) of the test. Means, I would know the possibility to find a difference between the two piles if it really exists. I hope all of this is correct so far....

HOWEVER: I don't have the option to measure the weights of the stones. All I have is the length of each stone and its content of iron. But this is not so bad, because previous data showed, that I can estimate the weight of each stone with a linear regression model containing "length" and "iron" as predictors. For sure the weights predicted by the model have an uncertainty. This uncertainty is quantified by the prediction interval of the model (at a chosen significance level, let's say 0.05) ... How would this uncertainty influence my power calculation mentioned above?

Not sure if I explained the problem good enough. So here is a simple example with some numbers from pilot data (These data contain: stone length, iron content and the true weights (ground truth)):

```
n = 100 %Number of stones

mu = 500 kg %Mean weight of stones (ground truth)

std = 200 kg %Standard deviation (ground truth)

effect size = 25/200 = 0.12 % expected difference is about 5% (25g) 

alpha = 0.05
```

-> power = 0.13 (okay, honestly quite bad, but it's only an example :) )

Now let's say the weights were not measured (ground truth) but estimated using a linear regression model (with "length" and "iron" as predictor). The model has a prediction interval of +/- 230 kg (based on 95% certainty).
The predicted values for weight would have a similar mean (~500 kg) and a similar std (~200 kg) as the ground truth data -> means, power calculation would lead to a similar result (~ 0.13). But, can I trust this power calculation, since the estimation of the single weight values have such a high uncertainty (based on the uncertainty of the predicting model). Do I need to consider the uncertainty of the single estimated values when calculating the statistical power of a t-test?

I'm really thankful for any comment (even if my question makes no sense ...)!!

Comment: A huge lurking issue is that your linear regression model surely is not completely accurate, because a stone's weight is not a perfectly linear function of the other variables.  This might be a primary consideration before worrying about the residual error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, you are right, a stones weight is not necessary a linear function of length and iron content. This is only an example I made up to understand how to deal in general with uncertainties of single observations when I do a statistical test. What  I want to know is: when I do a t-test on observations that are not measured, but estimated (by a model) with relatively large uncertainty, how will that influence the power of my t-test?

Comment: Could you explain how you conceive of measurement error and "estimated ... with relatively large uncertainty" as differing in this context?

Comment: hm... I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you mean, that I always have uncertainties in my weight values, no matter if I determine the weights by using a scale (no scale is perfect) or estimate the values using a model (no model is perfect as well)(?) I would agree to that, but when I estimate the weights with a model, the uncertainty is probably way larger than the uncertainty caused by a scale. In the example above, the standard deviation of all weights is around 200 kg, while the prediction interval of my model is +/- 230 kg...

Comment: Unless your uncertainties are so small you feel comfortable neglecting them, how you deal with them doesn't depend on whether they are small or large.  Indeed, the meanings of "small" and "large" are vague in the first place.  What likely matters most is if the errors in your model are correlated, which is rarely the case for measurement uncertainties.

Comment: oh okay, so if I understand you correctly: When I do a power calculation for a statistical test, the only thing that matter is the distribution of the values in both groups, but not the uncertainty of every single value. Even if the uncertainty of a single value is almost as large as the distribution over all values in the group, it doesn't matter? Would that also mean, that I don't need to care that my model predicts the values as accurate as possible? Optimize the model, to have a more accurate prediction, with less uncertainty, of the weights values would be useless? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as that.  The power calculation depends on how you model the data probabilistically and on the particulars of the test.  The details really matter.

Comment: thanks you so much for sharing all the information!!